# KSQL: Topk with associated fields

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

A question regarding the `topk` aggregation.
I have a stream of events, each event has three fields id, accountid, priority. I’m trying to have a view which has the list of ids group by accountid with top 5 priority,
I actually, came up with the query which gives the top 5 priority events

```
select topk(priority, 5), accountId 
 from events_stream 
 group by accountId 
 emit changes;
```

But I’m not able to associate the corresponding id for the event.
Sample event:

```
{
    "ROWTIME": 1588619792693,
    "ROWKEY": "99a5e4ac-a4be-4aa4-8222-3e95a4811994",
    "TIMESTAMP": 1588619792691,
    "ID": "99a5e4ac-a4be-4aa4-8222-3e95a4811994",
    "PRIORITY": 262,
    "ACCOUNTID": "345"
}
```

Would it be possible to have the `ids` with `topk` priority?

Comment: So you want to get the 5 ids for the correposding top 5 events with highest priority?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yes.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous my bad, I missed to mention that, top 5 ids with high priority grouped by account id.